# Appearance of the Cresent

Tags: the-moon

Does the latitude of your position on earth change the appearance of the cresent like it changes the position of other objects visible in the sky? Does it rotate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. If you are at a high latitude the crescent Moon will set looking like a reversed C orientation but in the tropics it will set more like a U orientation. Though the time of the year will also have some effect due to the angle of the ecliptic to the horizon.